# How to handle message processing failures on consumer end with Confluent Kafka?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am moving from a JMS based system to Kafka, which is responsible for synchronizing transactions between new and legacy system. Every message that is published by the new system must be successfully processed by the subscriber/consumer. I do not have to worry about the order of messages. Due to some design issues (pessimistic locking) in legacy system, once in a while, few transactions might fail when the message arrives, in that case I want that message to come back after some delay. I am trying to figure out how to handle this situation with Kafka.

My source and target applications are in .NET 4.6.1 and c#. I am using Confluent.Kafka v0.9.5 client library. Kafka is at version 0.10.

For the consumer application, I have disabled auto commit and explicitly invoking commitAsync method to commit the offset after a message is successfully processed. Here is how I create the consumer.

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"group.id", GroupId},
                    {"client.id", ClientId},
                    {"enable.auto.commit", false},
                    {"bootstrap.servers", _consumerConnectionConfig.BrokerUrl},
                    {
                        "default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                        {
                            {"auto.offset.reset", "latest"}
                        }
                    }
                };
var consumer = new Consumer<string, string>(config, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8), new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8));
```

This how polling is setup.

```
consumer.Subscribe(topics);

while (!SubscriberCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
      consumer.Poll(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
}
```

Here is the OnMessage event that is responsible for processing message

```
consumer.OnMessage += (sender, message) => {
   try
   {
     var payload = GetPayload(message);
     if (_messageHandlerService.ProcessMessage(payload))
     {                 
      consumer.CommitAsync(message).Wait(SubscriberCancellationToken);   
     }
     else
     {
         //(case 1) Now what should I do?????
     }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   { 
        Log.Error("Unable to process xyz messages", ex);
        throw; //??? (Case 2) should I throw the exception or should I not?
   }
};
```

If the message can be successfully processed, I invoke commitAsync and that works like a charm. Now my question is what should I do, when I am unable to process a message (case 1) or some exception occurs (case 2). What choices do I have to handle these two situations?

In the JMS world, for (case 1), I applied a delayed republishing strategy. Basically I wait for 1 min and then republish the message to the same topic and commit the current message, so that republished message will come back again. For some reason, if I cannot republish, I just keep retrying until I can or until the process restarts. If the process restarted before I could republish, the uncommitted messages come back and the cycle starts all over again..

Once republish succeeds, If there are other messages already waiting on the topic, they will now start moving thru and the train goes in a circle until everything is processed. Every time I cannot process the message as in case 1, I log an error, appropriate alerts are generated based on it, so that application support team can take some action just in case if they have to fix some data in the legacy system. Until then the message keeps on failing and then it is republished.

And for Case 2, I was logging the details and throwing an exception in the JMS implementation. I now wonder may be I should handle just like case 1.

Now my question is how should I handle these two situations in the world of Kafka? Are there any better options?

Answer (score 1):

Few options

One is to push these messages to another Kafka topic and let a dedicated consumer deal with it, or,

Retry within your consumer until that particular message gets processed or you reach a certain threshold. This can be done by calling pause method on your consumer to stop message consumption temporarily (I am talking from a Java consumer perspective, pls confirm with the C# client), run your retry logic. Please make sure that you also continue to invoke poll as well (otherwise the consumer will be kicked out of the group and its partitions will be re-balanced). Once you're done re-trying, call the resume method to continue processing - now the poll method will return records from Kafka

Comment: Thank you. Let me try the pause and resume feature. I will post the results with c# client

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Confluent.Kafka c# client does not have pause and resume methods yet.

Answer (score 0):

Error handling can be much more straightforward, using an higher level library such as "my" Silverback (https://github.com/BEagle1984/silverback that helps you dealing with them.

It implements the concept of error policies that you can use to configure how you consumer has to behave in case of errors (retry / skip / move the message to another topic).

```cs
...
.AddKafkaEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints
    .Configure(config => 
        {
            config.BootstrapServers = "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092"; 
        })
    .AddInbound(endpoint => endpoint
        .ConsumeFrom("order-events")
        .Configure(config => 
            {
                config.GroupId = "my-consumer";
            })
        .OnError(policy => policy
            .Retry(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .ThenSkip())));
```

See https://silverback-messaging.net/concepts/broker/inbound.html#error-handling.

(Silverback is built on top of Confluent.Kafka.)